# what does 떡하니 mean?

Tags: vocabulary

this is the sentence
그래서 처음으로 나아가 대문 빗장을 따고 ***떡하니*** 뒷짐을 지고서는,

+++
here is more context if needed

> 똑 어린애 장난 같은 일이다. 쑥스럽기도 하다. 그러나 이것은 나의 소시민적 행복감을 만족시켜 줄 수 있는 일이다. 나보다도
>   어머님께서 더욱 그렇게 함으로써 행복을 느끼시는 모양이다. 그러면 다른 것으로는 효도를 못해도 이 힘 안 들이고 쉽게 행할 수
>   있는 것으로나마 노래(老來)하신 어머님을 위로해 드리고 기쁘게 해드리리라 마음먹었다.
>
> 그래서 처음으로 나아가 대문 빗장을 따고 ***떡하니*** 뒷짐을 지고서는,

Comment: 여기서 말하는 `떡하니`는 `당당하다` `당돌하다` `뻔뻔하다` 이런 뜻인 것 같네요.

Answer (score 6):

"떡하니" in a Korean dictionary is given the following definition:

> 보란 듯이 의젓하거나 여유가 있게

When translated, its meaning is close to:

*"mature and relaxed(as if one has time to spare), as if with an intent to purposefully show other people"*

Therefore in the sentence of question, the act of 뒷짐(clasping hands behind your back) was done with such style.

Answer (score 3):

I’d translate it as ‘unabashedly’, ‘unapologetically’ or ‘as if to show off’.

‘떡’ is an 의태어 that describes a clear visual presence of someone or something, often against (implied) expectations.

E.g. ‘어제 지갑을 잃어버렸는 줄 알았는데, 오늘 보니 탁자에 떡 있네.’ — I thought I’d lost my wallet yesterday, but then *there* it was on the table today.